# Building a conditional check constraint

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

I'm trying to build a conditional check constraint for my table TBL_AFIL, which has two fields:

- Fec_Renun DATE
- flg_afil INTEGER

Constraint: IF flg_afil=1 THEN Fec_Renun can not be NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_AFIL
ADD CONSTRAINT FecRenun_Not_Null CHECK (Fec_Renun IS not NULL and flg_afil =1) ;
```

But it throws this error:

```
ORA-02293: cannot validate (FecRenun_Not_Null) - check constraint violated
```

But when I run this query, it returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_AFIL
WHERE FEC_RENUN IS NULL
AND FLG_AFIL =1;
```

I know that to this constraint I could add `ENABLE NOVALIDATE`, but I'm intrigued why can't build this constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CHECK (NOT (flag_afil = 1 AND fec_renum IS NULL))
```

Comment: Equivalently, `CHECK (flag_afil != 1 OR fec_renum IS NOT NULL))` (from De Morgan's Laws), or since the flag can only have one of two values, `CHECK (flag_afil = 0 OR fec_renum IS NOT NULL))`. I find the last to be the most intuitive.